# Append trailing slash to every outgoing Ajax request with JQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

Django prefers (requires) all urls to have a trailing slash by default.

How can I configure jQuery to automatically append a slash to every url I'm hitting with AJAX calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to modify every outgoing ajax request via beforeSend as follows:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        settings.url = ensureTrailingSlash(url);
    }
});
```

As to implementation of `ensureTrailingSlash` here is an example implementation (I haven't tested edge cases):

```
var maybeAppendSlash = function (url) {
    if (url[url.length-1] !== "/") {
        url += '/';
    }
    return url;
};

var ensureTrailingSlash = function (url) {
    var parser = document.createElement('a');
    parser.href = url;
    parser.pathname = maybeAppendSlash(parser.pathname);
    return parser.href;
};
```

A more complete version can be found at this repo:

https://github.com/ustun/ensure-trailing-slash-for-jquery-ajax/blob/master/ensure_slash.js

Comment: +1 You can use `url.slice(-1)` instead of `url[url.length-1]`.